# WebRTC or WebSockets for broadcast streaming video?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, architecture, webrtc

My architecture is [[arch0.dot](https://gist.github.com/SamuelMarks/a589f11e70db8baba4187e77ce35f1d0)]:

[image: circo]

One laptop is [broadcast] streaming two video and two audio streams to all the [JavaScript] clients. Additionally I have a WebSockets connection for chat.

Server [written in Node.JS] must:

- Record chats (currently does this through an append only file)
- Record video and audio streams (client currently does this through [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder); but want to move to server)

Related: [WebRTC vs Websockets: If WebRTC can do Video, Audio, and Data, why do I need Websockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18799364)

Which technology makes the most sense for this common architecture, in late 2017?

Answer (score 3):

Both WebRTC and WebSockets is a good technical choice. When you're building a WebRTC service there's two different parts; a peer connection and a signaling server. The signaling server handles all the metadata transfers between the peers (so they can communicate before the peer connection is ongoing). Typically you'll have a WebSocket connection for receiving events and a REST API for sending events.

It sounds that what you're asking for is a media server. A media server makes the WebRTC connection to a peer-to-media-server-to-peer connection, instead of a peer-to-peer connection. Because all the media goes through the media server, you can record all the traffic (audio/video/data), and there's no need to use MediaRecorder at the client side.

You wont need any special support at the server side for the one way communication of audio/video streams, that can be done client side with WebRTC.

Regarding media server I've been looking at https://github.com/versatica/mediasoup/ since they seem to be used a lot and maintained for a pretty long time.

Comment: You mentioned recording and then recommended mediasoup. AFAIK, Mediasoup does not support recording. Janus is the most suitable IMHO followed by kurento and jitsi if recording is a concern

Answer (score -4):

Websockets is a 10yr old concept, WebRTC is fairly new (few years) but available in all modern browsers: Chrome, Firefox, Edge.  Overall I would say WebRTC is intended as a replacement for Websockets.  Now that it's been in browsers a year or more, it's a fairly mature and stable solution.

Comment: So what is your definitive answer? Your answer is not really clear or are you trying to be clever with your answer and not give a definitive answer?